# Use html hyperlinks to index file folders

Tags: html, file-browser

I am trying to index the file folders on my local computer using a html file. I set hyperlinks to the folders, when click the link, the internet browser (firefox in my case) lists the files contained in the folder. However, is it possible to open the file browser (linux) when click the link, rather than listing the files within the internet browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible because HTML controls web objects and wouldn't be able to open and search a path in a file browser. For that has to do with the physical computers file system not the internet.
If you need to me explain more just let me know